# How to generate a BinaryField in a mongo init shell script

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

In my Python code I have a UserDocument which looks like this ->

```
class UserDocument(DynamicDocument):
    user_id = IntField()
    email = StringField(unique=True)
    password = BinaryField()
    salt = BinaryField()
```

I would like to populate my database with a new user during the instantiation of my Docker container. Related to the document it's pretty easy, I just have create a shell script and copy it into `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

Here is the script for the user creation ->

```
#!/bin/sh

# This is supposed to generate the BinaryField
SALT=$(xxd -u -l 64 -p /dev/urandom)
BINARY_SALT=$(echo -n $SALT | xxd -r -p)

mongo -- "inup" <<EOF
    var rootUser = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME';
    var rootPassword = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD';
    var inup = db.getSiblingDB('inup');
    inup.auth(rootUser, rootPassword);

    db.user_document.insert({
      user_id: 1,
      email: 'toto@gmail.com',
      password: 'password123',
      salt: $BINARY_SALT # This doesn't work
    });
EOF
```

This works but I have a problem. **How can I generate a BinaryField for the attribut salt ?**

Have a nice days and thanks for the replies !

Answer (score 0):

Binary data in MongoDB are created from [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string, e.g.

```
SALT=$(xxd -u -l 64 -p /dev/urandom)
BASE64_SALT=$(echo -n $SALT | base64)

db.user_document.insertOne({"salt" : BinData(0, "$BASE64_SALT")});
```

See [Binary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/#binary)

Or you store the Base64 as string.

```
db.user_document.insertOne({"salt" : "$BASE64_SALT"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay ! I tried both and I got SyntaxError: ` unterminated string literal @(shell):5:26` and `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'`. I also have `ReferenceError: M0Q4IEJENERGOTdGQkZENjQ0RThDQzM5NkU1N0EzMkRBNTZGMTkyQzYwQUM4ODc1MUY3RDkzODYx is not defined.`

Comment: Please check your code, seems to be a simply syntax error.